# Does notepad++ regular expressions engine (scintilla) support substring escaping (smth. like "\Q.*[escaped string]()+\E")?

Tags: regex, escaping, notepad++, scintilla

Subj.

I mean that I don't want to paste dozens of '\' into search pattern. Obvious way is to use pair of perl-style special characters:

- \Q -- quote (disable) pattern metacharacters till \E
- \E -- end case modification

Example: \Qtext here is excaped ".*[]+" symbols doesn't have special meaning\E.

I found, that \Q...\E doesn't work in notepad++, so I wonder if there is another ability to escape substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By now Scintilla uses PCRE which means you can use `\Q` and `\E`. Old answer below, because I find it interesting that historically the old “regexes” weren't even regular ;)

---

No. Scintilla only supports very minimal regular expression syntax. [The documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators) even highlights more unsupported parts of regular expressions<sup>1</sup>.

I'd say you should get a decent editor or do the replacing with other tools :-)

---

<sup>1</sup> This even includes alternation (`|`) and if I'm not mistaken this limits the power of those regular expressions (even though they support backreferences in the match) to an extended subset of regular languages. For example, I do not think that the language {ab, bc} can be represented, although it clearly is regular.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation's limits page.

Comment: This is no longer true - as of version 6, Notepad++ supports (uses?) PCRE - the perl-compatible regular expressions library; as far a I can tell, that quickly elevates it from one of the worst levels of regexp support to top-notch support!

Comment: I can confirm that. Just upgraded from pre 6.0.0 version to 6.4.5 and indeed it supports substring escaping.